# PortfolioAnalytics in R - optimize.portfolio() results in NaN for annualized return

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

I am learning how to use `PortfolioAnalytics` package in R to do rebalancing a portfolio every quarters. I collected the data on 19 large-cap stocks in US and China using `qmao` package, and then compute the quarterly return. Everything works fine until I call the function `optimize.portfolio.rebalancing()`. It kept giving me the following error message, together with `NaN` as a result for `Annualized Portfolio Rebalancing Return`:

> VaR calculation produces unreliable result (risk over 100%) for
>   column: 1 : 1.12020244277128 ES calculation produces unreliable result
>   (risk over 100%) for column: 1 : 1.14791543855955 VaR calculation
>   produces unreliable result (risk over 100%) for column: 1 :
>   1.13372707060527 ES calculation produces unreliable result (risk over 100%) for column: 1 : 1.14960946412769

**Full code for reproducing**

```
#get the stock price data for 19 large-cap stocks from 2008/10/29 to 2018/11/04 and compute its quarterly return.
#Make the boxplot of the quarterly return for all 19 stocks. 
library(qmao)
library(quantmod)
library(data.table)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(car)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(foreach)
library(iterators)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.quadprog)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel()

symbols <- c("IBM", "GOOG", "JPM", "BAC", "TGT", "WMT", "AAPL", "TSLA", "AMZN", "PG", "EBAY", "NKE", "MSFT", "GE", "TCEHY", "SBUX", "GM", "TM", "BABA")
data.env <- new.env()
startDate = as.Date("2008-10-29") #Specify what date to get the prices from
endDate = as.Date("2018-11-04")
getSymbols(symbols, env = data.env ,from= startDate ,to= endDate)
pf <- PF(symbols,env = data.env,silent=TRUE) # consolidated xts-object
pfMth <- pf[endpoints(pf,on='quarters'),]   # get quarterly endpoints
pfMthRets <- ROC(pfMth,type='discrete')   
pfMthRets <- pfMthRets[complete.cases(pfMthRets),]
tail(pfMthRets)

#compute S&P 500 quarterly return from 2008/10/29 to 2018/11/04
startDate = as.Date("2008-10-29") #Specify what date to get the prices from
endDate = as.Date("2018-11-04")
sp500 <- getSymbols("^GSPC",auto.assign = FALSE ,from= startDate ,to= endDate)
sp500 <- PF("sp500",env = sp500,silent=TRUE) # consolidated xts-object
sp500Mth <- sp500[endpoints(sp500,on='quarters'),]   # get monthly endpoints
sp500MthRets <- ROC(sp500Mth,type='discrete')   
sp500MthRets <- sp500MthRets[complete.cases(sp500MthRets),]

#constraint the portfolio of stock with certain constraints and solve for the optimal portfolio (in terms of minimum variance and maximum return)
returns <- pfMthRets[, 1:ncol(pfMthRets)]
colnames(returns) <- c("IBM", "GOOG", "JPM", "BAC", "TGT", "WMT", "AAPL", "TSLA", "AMZN", "PG", "EBAY", "NKE", "MSFT", "GE", "TCEHY", "SBUX", "GM", "TM", "BABA")
portf.dn <- portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(returns))
# Add constraint such that the portfolio weights sum to 0*
portf.dn <- add.constraint(portf.dn, type="active")
# Add box constraint such that no asset can have a weight of greater than
# 20% or less than -20%
portf.dn <- add.constraint(portf.dn, type="box", min=-0.2, max=0.2)
# Add constraint such that the portfolio beta is between -0.25 and 0.25
betas <- t(CAPM.beta(pfMthRets,sp500MthRets)) #beta = cov(Ra,Rb)/var(R)
portf.dn <- add.constraint(portf.dn, type="factor_exposure", B=betas,
                           lower=-0.25, upper=0.25)

# Add objective to maximize portfolio return with a target of 0.15
portf.dn <- add.objective(portf.dn, type="return", name="mean")
# Add objective to minimize portfolio StdDev with a target of 0.005
portf.dn <- add.objective(portf.dn, type="risk", name="var")
# transaction cost constraint
portf.dn <- add.constraint(portfolio = portf.dn, type = "transaction_cost", ptc=0.01)

# Run the optimization with rebalancing every quarters
opt.dn <- optimize.portfolio.rebalancing(R=pfMthRets, portf.dn,
                             optimize_method="random",rebalance_on = "quarters",maxSR = TRUE,
                             training_period = 3)
opt.dn
```

**My questions:**

(1) It also seems to me that we have **no** clue to know which of the given constraints and objectives result in feasible solutions (for example, we can have `10` constraints, `2` simple objectives (minimize risk, and maximize return given certain level of risk), and then the result is `NaN` for weights assigned to `19` stocks above). So how do we determine which constraint to add to make it feasible?

(2) If I want to plot the **efficient frontier** every quarters, how can I do that? I tried doing this with `meanSigma.ef = create.EfficientFrontier(R=pfMthRets, portfolio=portf.dn, type="mean-StdDev", n.portfolios = 25)` but I keeps getting the error message "Error in seq.default(from = minret, to = maxret, length.out = n.portfolios) : 'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite."

Comment: I am sorry but nobody here wants to help me with this issue?? I am still stumbled upon creating the efficient frontier using `create.EfficientFrontier()` function from PortfolioAnalytics? Any help would really be appreciated.