# Plot quarterly return of various stocks with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, trendline

I have a data frame `dt1` consisting of 4 columns `c("Date", "ticker", "price", "idx_price").` I want to plot the quarterly return of various stocks, so I used the following code:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x = date, y = idx_price, group=1, color=ticker)) +   geom_line() 
+  theme_bw() + ggtitle("Price Developments") +   xlab("Date") + ylab("Price\n(Indexed 2000 = 1)") +   scale_color_discrete(name = "Company")
```

Portion of `dt1`

```
      date ticker     price idx_price
  1: 1-2000    IBM  79.57278 1.0000000
  2: 2-2000    IBM  78.47529 0.9862077
  3: 3-2000    IBM  83.02403 1.0433722
  4: 4-2000    IBM  69.00775 0.8672280
  5: 1-2001    IBM  72.41976 0.9101071
  6: 2-2001    IBM  78.59155 0.9876687
  7: 3-2001    IBM  72.57718 0.9120855
  8: 4-2001    IBM  78.96643 0.9923799
 17: 1-2004    IBM  68.45035 0.8602231
 18: 2-2004    IBM  64.43103 0.8097119
 19: 3-2004    IBM  61.27942 0.7701053
 20: 4-2004    IBM  67.05470 0.8426839
 21: 1-2005    IBM  67.16391 0.8440563
 22: 2-2005    IBM  56.04156 0.7042805
 23: 3-2005    IBM  58.89009 0.7400783
 24: 4-2005    IBM  61.31186 0.7705130
 25: 1-2006    IBM  59.70685 0.7503427
 26: 2-2006    IBM  58.99930 0.7414507
 27: 3-2006    IBM  57.72717 0.7254638
 28: 4-2006    IBM  67.46785 0.8478759       
 77: 3-2004   GOOG  55.06072 1.0000000
 78: 4-2004   GOOG  84.94897 1.5428236
 79: 1-2005   GOOG  94.04130 1.7079564
 80: 2-2005   GOOG 120.64827 2.1911860
 81: 3-2005   GOOG 147.10960 2.6717706
 82: 4-2005   GOOG 188.86456 3.4301144
 83: 1-2006   GOOG 193.88590 3.5213108
 84: 2-2006   GOOG 196.84937 3.5751327
 85: 3-2006   GOOG 194.64647 3.5351243
 86: 4-2006   GOOG 231.50996 4.2046305
 8: 3-2014   BABA  89.81250 1.0000000
 9: 4-2014   BABA 102.63641 1.1427853
10: 1-2015   BABA  90.24852 1.0048548
11: 2-2015   BABA  85.93667 0.9568453
12: 3-2015   BABA  72.70969 0.8095720
13: 4-2015   BABA  78.46703 0.8736761
14: 1-2016   BABA  70.37623 0.7835906
15: 2-2016   BABA  78.25656 0.8713327
16: 3-2016   BABA  92.67812 1.0319068
17: 4-2016   BABA  96.27968 1.0720076
```

I got the graph like this as a result of the code above, but I can't understand why it has a trend line connecting different quarters...Can anyone please help explain to me why there is such a line, and whether this means the code above is incorrect?

[image: The trend line in pink]

Comment: what u want to be expected plot contains? and can u let me know y used `group = 1` ?

Comment: Your code calls `geom_line()` and therefore plots a line, not bars. And you should `group = ticker`.

Comment: @saisaran: I used `group=1` as I searched through the similar question for how to plot quarterly data;( I guess I am dumb...

@RuiBarradas: thank you. I tried that and it works perfectly!! Can you please help with another question that I posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53146031/portfolioanalytics-in-r-optimize-portfolio-results-in-nan-for-annualized-ret? 

Really appreciate your help.